# How to format dates on frontend

Tags: reactjs, recharts, cube.js

I am using the React (recharts) integration of cube and was wondering how to format dates or "weeks" instead of having the full ISOdate.

For example `Week 39` instead of `2021-09-27T00:00:00.000` on the charts and views.

I tried looking at the docs but can't find it. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the community @John.may! Are you using any localization library like moment.js, Luxon ? You can use them to transform the DateTime to week number and pass it to the charting library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reformat your date data before passing it to the chart, use moment.js to get the week number [Documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/)

```
moment(date).week();
```

make sure to set the locale region because the week starts on Monday or Sunday depends on the region:

```
//this is for France
import 'moment/locale/fr'
moment.locale('fr')
```

(EDIT) : You can use other libraries for this purpose such as [Day.js](https://day.js.org/) or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started).

Comment: Very minor nitpick, but I would actually recommend [dayjs](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs), the successor to moments, as the latter is deprecated (although still safe to use)

Comment: @Heidiki, thank you very much. I am using the antd based recharts that comes with cubejs (one of the dashboard options) and I can't find where I could use this with Cube. It seems it uses an object that cubes "useCubeQuery" returns called "ResultSet", which for a table has the "tableColumns" and "tablePivot" functions for example. This makes me think there must be a way to do this from the Cube config, is this something you might have an idea what to do with? Thanks!

Comment: @programmer.john.may have you tried using ResultSet.chartPivot( )?

what I always do if am getting the data for a chart is use ResultSet.chartPivot( ) and map the results to a structure that will work with the chart.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using `moment.js` since it has been deprecated try using [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) ,it offers more customization
Here is the snippet of using `date-fns`.

```
    import { format } from "date-fns";
    
    const getWeek = new Date('2021-09-27T00:00:00.000')
    const result = format(getWeek,"Io")) //here "Io" stands for ISO week of year,
   //result -> 39th
```

In fact you can modify as per your conveniant, how to display the week here is the document of that [date-fns format](https://date-fns.org/v2.24.0/docs/format)
just in case you want the visual I have added a **codesandbox**  [week format using date-fns](https://codesandbox.io/s/formatter-forked-3qzss?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: It's nice that you recommended an alternative, but how should OP use date-fns to achieve the same result?

Comment: I have added the code snippet you can follow @Moistbobo